# RPI3b+: UART serial communication problem

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, serial, uart

I have my RPI setup to communicate serially with another board. Currently, I have a usb to serial converter which is plugged into one of the RPI ports. This works well but, I want to take that out and use the native serial pins on the RPI.

Here's my setup for testing/verification. I've remapped the full UART (auto-set to bluetooth) on my RPI3B+ to the GPIO pins. The GPIO pins go through an isolator and to the serial side of the converter chip which then feeds back into the RPI. This creates a loop where I should be able to write to one of the ports, read off the other port, and verify correct transmission.

I have some python code that manages this for me:

```
import time
import serial

ser1 = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0', #Replace ttyS0 with ttyAM0 for Pi1,Pi2,Pi0
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
    timeout=1
)

ser2 = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/serial0', #Replace ttyS0 with ttyAM0 for Pi1,Pi2,Pi0
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    timeout=1
)

counter1=1
counter2=-1

while 1:
    print('Begin1 +' + str(counter1))
    ser1.write(bytes("1Write: +%d \n"%(counter1), 'utf-8'))
    ser2.write(bytes("2Write:  %d \n"%(counter2), 'utf-8'))

    #time.sleep(1)

    print('Begin2 ' + str(counter2))
    print(ser1.readlines())
    print(ser2.readlines())

    time.sleep(1)

    counter1 += 1
    counter2 -= 1
```

And this kinda-sorta works. Here's an excerpt of the printout.

```
 Begin1 +250
 Begin2 -250
 [b'"\x06`\x80\xc0\x80p\x00\x00H"@\x00\x04\x14']
 [b'\xb9{\xdf\xbf\xfb\x83\xbb\x9b\xefgg\xf3']
 Begin1 +251
 Begin2 -251
 [b'0Write:   01 \x00\x1a']
 [b'3Write: +?751*']
 Begin1 +252
 Begin2 -252
 [b'\x00U@iP\x80p\x00@\xb4I!\x00\x04\xa0\xf8']
 [b'\xff\xdd\xfb\xfc\xef~\xe8\xeb\x9b\xbf\xf7}\xd1']
 Begin1 +253
 Begin2 -253
 [b'"\x06`@`e0\x00\x00$"4\x01 \n']
 [b'\xb9{\xdf\xaf\xfb\x83\xbb\x9b\xef\xe7g\xf3']
```

Sometimes it works a little nicer:

```
 Begin1 +1
 Begin2 -1
 [b'\x11\x15\x0c\x04\x18\x01\x18\x80\x94 \x00\x00\x14']
 [b'\xbdz\x9e\xbf\xfb\x83\xbbs\xa7\xff']
 Begin1 +2
 Begin2 -2
 [b'0Write:    \x00\n']
 [b'3Write: +?2*']
 Begin1 +3
 Begin2 -3
 [b'0Write: (! \x00\n']
 [b'3Write: +?3*']
 Begin1 +4
 Begin2 -4
 [b'0Write:  $ \x00\n']
 [b'3Write: +=4*']
```

It occasionally reads and writes how it should, but there's a lot of garbage too.
The port "ser1" represents how I used to be sending data, which worked when it was routed through the converter chip to the board. So the code for opening ser1 shouldn't have to change. The board requires an even parity with 1 stop bit.

Does anyone have an idea why this communication setup isn't working?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just do a simple loop back?  I do not understand why you are writing to two serial ports and reading from two serial ports.  A diagram if what you are doing may help.

Comment: I've done a loop back and it works, but I don't need to verify that the port is writing. I need to verify that  the port is writing in the correct format. The converter works to talk to the board. The serial does not yet. So I believe the format is not right.